# Return object where validation failed on DataMember

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a `DataContract` class that looks something like

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id)]
    [Required]
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

I have a class that represents error responses as

```
[DataContract]
public class ErrorResponse
{
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    [Required]
    public int Code { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "message")]
    [Required]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is return an instance of the `ErrorModel` class if the validation on `id` fails (in this case, if it was not specified.

Is there some attribute I can use to achieve this? Something like

```
[Required(new ErrorResponse { Code = 1, Message = "id field is required })]
```

Comment: Return it where?  Validators are expected to return a `ValidationResult` object which usually is based on a message or a message + field(s) in error per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Return it to the client. But I don't want to return just a json or xml string because I need the media formatter to take care of that.